# htaccess: how to stop it after first match

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, cpanel

this is my htaccess file :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        # Turn mod_rewrite on
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteBase /
       
        RewriteRule ^getlastversion(.*)$ /lastversion.php$1 [R=301,NC,L,QSA]

        # this is temporary and should be removed 
        RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example\.com\?$1 [R=301,NC,L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

browsing `mysite.com/getlastversion` redirect to `example.com?lastversion.php`(second rule),whereas i need it to be redirected to `/lastversion.php`(first rule)

Comment: Hello alex, May I ask here, could you please do let us know how our solutions went? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this rule with a negative lookahead condition:

```sh
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
       
RewriteRule ^getlastversion(.*)$ /lastversion.php$1 [R=301,NC,L,QSA]

# this is temporary and should be removed 
RewriteRule ^(?!lastversion\.php)(.*)$ http://example.com?$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

`(?!lastversion\.php)` is negative lookahead that will skip this rule if we have `/lastversion.php` at the start of the URL.

Make sure to test this rule after fully clearing your browser cache.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your shown samples, could you please try following. Please make sure to clear your cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
       
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^getlastversion(.*)/?$ /lastversion.php$1 [R=301,NC,L,QSA]

# this is temporary and should be removed 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !lastversion\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com?$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```